# send data from express.js to react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So, I need to send data from express as backend to react.js as frontend I don't know that if I am using the right method or not

so what I am trying to do is when I am at mywebsite.com/home I get all posts from database
which it will be the username and his post ... but what I get here is I am at  mywebsite.com it insta display the data coming from /api and fast change to the data coming from /s

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import "./App.css";
import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const {user, body} = useFetchData();

  return (
    <div>
      <label className='username'> user is here {user}</label>
      <br></br>
      <label className='body'>body is here {body}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

function useFetchData() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setData);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/s')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setData);
  }, []);
  return data;
}


export default App;
```

back end

```
// server/index.js

const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../facebook-clone/build')));

// Handle GET requests to /api route
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ 
        user: "zeyad alaa",
        body: "this is body 1"
    });
      
  });

  app.get("/s", (req, res) => {
    res.json({  user: "zeyad ",
    body: "this is body 2" });
      
  });
  


// All other GET requests not handled before will return our React app
// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../facebook-clone/build', 'error.html'));
  
//   console.log("s3");
// });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

any idea why it's doing this ?
and why it's not waiting me to enter to mywebsite.com/home ?

I know I am missing a lot of things here but can u help me knowing these concepts ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because in the `useFetchData` hook you manage both data from `/api` and `/s` inside of a single state `data`.

you have defined two `useEffect` inside of the `useFetchData` so both will be executed once before the component have been mounted. In you case the call to `/api` completed before the call to `/s` that will trigger the updated of the `data` state which by the way trigger the display of data from `/api` few second letter the second `useEffect` in which you perform a fetch request to `/s` completed which trigger also the update of `data` state  to the new data get from `/s`. As the state `data` have changed It will trigger the rerender of the component with the new data.

Comment: okay correct so how i am going to send alot of data (posts)to my react js (front end) ?

Comment: As you have two API endpoint `/api`  and `/s` you have to define in which case you render data from `/api` and `/s`. By defining that, you can define what content will be render when data for `/api` is already available to the fronend and what to do when the content from `/s` become available